# How can we send FormData to a web api with additional parameters?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am sending a file input in FormData to a web api as below. The api method expects one additional parameter as well but the below code works only without the parameter in api. How can I send the additional parameter to the api.
Thanks for any suggestions!

```
<div>
    <label for="add">Add Customer</label>
    <input type="file" onchange="AddCust(event)" />
</div>

function AddCust(event) 
{
    Add("testtype", event.target.files[0]);
}

function Add(type, file)
{
    var imageData = new FormData();

    imageData.append("myfile", file);

    $.ajax({
        url: _uri + '/party/Add', 
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: imageData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#log").append("Add - Success " + data.toString() + "</br>");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $("#log").append("Add - Error " + xhr.responseText + "</br>");
        }
});
```

Web API:

```
[HttpPost]
public async void Add(string customertype)
{
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));

    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out that below does not work.

url: _uri + '/party/Add/testtype'

It has to be specified in url

url: _uri + '/party/Add?customertype=' + 'testtype'